# Azure Synapse External Table Location parameterization

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Is it possible to pass a parameter(folder /file path) to the location of Azure Synapse External Table?

Comment: do you mean making the path dynamic?

Comment: Yes, we were looking to add the filenames along with the path for a particular scenario. Now we have dropped it started using a different methodology

Comment: I think external table location should be static, otherwise the code and logic get pretty complex. But there are workearrounds, depend on your use case. For example, you can add an extra column to your files (SOURCE_FILE), and filter your results by the column: `SELECT * FROM YOUR_EXTERNAL_TABLE WHERE SOURCE_FILE LIKE '%some_pattrn'`

Comment: @VB_, This can be achieved using dynamic SQL. We have used dynamic SQL to pass the parameter values to the location.

Answer (score 1):

We have used dynamic SQL to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you show an example query here by what you mean. this answer seems incomplete